# From Blender to THREEJS, export with GLTF a mesh with UV texture & material color: material color lost

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

In my  game, i use mesh (skeleton, animations and materials without texture) made with Blender (2.79b) ,then exported in glb format (gltf binary v2). In THREEJS scene, i modify dynamicaly the color of some materials by changing the color. I use the r109 version for THREEJS. The gltf exporter version is 1.2.0

I wanted to improve my mesh by adding an UV texture to my materials, like adding a decals.

Unfortunately, in the THREEJS scene, if the texture rendering is ok, the color of the material is black.

To better explain my problem, i used the default cube of Blender. I created:

- UV map
- 1 material per face with a different color + 1 UV texture

To build my UV texture:

- "Smart UV project"
- UVs -> Export UV Layout  (cube.png)

[image: UV export]
(change Fill opacity to 0)

- Modified cube.png with Gimp.
- Image -> Open image (cube.png)

I let the default options of Blender.

[image]

Then i exported the mesh as usual with the GLTF exporter and rendered into THREEJS scene.

```
var ambientLight =new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1 );
ambientLight.position.set( 0,5, 0 );
scene.add( ambientLight );
var otherCube=new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "blue"}) )
otherCube.position.x=-2
scene.add( otherCube);

 var GLTF_loader=new THREE.GLTFLoader();
 GLTF_loader.load( '/cube.glb', function(geometry)  {
   var mesh=geometry.scene.getObjectByName( "Cube" );
   scene.add(mesh);
 });
```

[image]

The texture rendering seems ok but the color of each face is lost. I built a blue cube to show it is not a problem of light into the scene.

It looks like an alpha problem, i tried to activate certain options in Blender before export but that didn't change anything. In addition, the rendering in Blender is good.

What would be the options to use in Blender or/and THREEJS so that i get the color of my faces? (and change the color later)

Comment: i'm thinking; that object looks really dark, even the textures. Did you add a light to the scene?

Comment: yes, i have a HemisphereLight into the scene. I added a AmbientLight but it changes nothing.

Comment: And I see you edited your answer accordingly. Props for that. You are right in that it is a alpha problem. I did some tests with mapping a semi-transparent texture on a red cube. The color shows as black whether I set the material's color or the geometry face's vertexColors. Maybe @gman knows a solution? (he seems to know his thee.js) In this case, a simple cube, i would generate them in js and use a shaderMaterial. Or double up the boxes. inside one with facecolors, outside one (slightly scaled up)  with the decal and transparancy enabled. But i don't know if that would suits your project.

Comment: I take a cube example for here, but my final mesh with  is more complex (500+ faces). I guess there is an easy solution to solve but i don't know enough Blender, it is a real gas plant for me!

Comment: Maybe double check the export settings? Blender side should be fine. Gltf also supports basecolor and textures.. I bet it's in three.js.. Sorry I can't help you any further. I did find this: https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry. Looks so good.

Comment: I forget if there was even a way in Blender 2.79 to enable alpha blending in glTF export.  I know that Blender 2.8x can do it by setting the material mode in Eevee to "Alpha Blend".  You could also convert the .glb to .gltf and then hand-edit the glTF material (for example in VSCode).

Comment: Does the model look any different in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ or https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/?

Comment: DecalGeometry seems interesting but is far from what i want to do. 
The only options in GLTF exporter about alpha is "Export Vertex Color Alpha". I tried it and gives nothing. 
I tried the 2 sandboxes (threejs&babylonjs) and the rendering is the same as my scene.

Comment: I solved with shader materials.

Comment: For some reason SO stopped alerting me on this thread.. I'm happy to see that you managed to solve it :) I did think about this for a while, came to the same conclusion; shaderMaterial. Nicely done